# Subtracting the values ​in a list that I specify closest to the values ​in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist, position

I have 3 cursor point at the list, here is the list: `list = [(929, 412),(1007, 281),(762, 176)]` and I have "ignored list" `ignored_list = [(123,848),(928, 407)]`. I want to delete values ​​that are close to each other, as a example first value of first list (list[0]) and second value of second list (ignored_list[1]), I want it to have a value range of +8 and -8. Another example (147, 412),(427, 281),(457, 177) and (421, 284),(594, 123), I want to extract second value at first list for second list well new list `(147, 412),(457, 177)`.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise we cannot tell you where your error is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood you correctly:

```py
lst = [(929, 412), (1007, 281), (762, 176)]
ignored_list = [(123, 848), (928, 407)]

N = 8


def is_near(a, b, threshold=N):
    return abs(a[0] - b[0]) <= threshold and abs(a[1] - b[1]) <= threshold


out = [a for a in lst if not any(is_near(a, b) for b in ignored_list)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[(1007, 281), (762, 176)]
```

Comment: thats what i want man thanks so much!

Comment: I'd still like to close this question, the way it is worded will definitely not help anyone else.